# BottomSheet animation duration

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, bottom-sheet

I am using the BottomSheet view for one of my layouts. For a very specific case, I need the animation duration of the BottomSheet which slides in the layout via the setState(...) method. It should be something around 400ms but I would prefer not to have a "magic" number for that case.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

The duration of [BottomSheetBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior#BottomSheetBehavior(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet)) animation triggered by [setState](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior#setState(int)) or touch events depends on various conditions.

`BottomSheetBehavior` internally uses [ViewDragHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/customview/widget/ViewDragHelper) which determines animation duration time inside [computeAxisDuration()](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-support-v4/blob/507f07137d6cedf9591597896d91c7021d18538d/src/java/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.java#L624) private method.
This duration depends on some arbitrary values and cannot change it by official API:

```
public class ViewDragHelper {
    ...
    private static final int BASE_SETTLE_DURATION = 256; // ms
    private static final int MAX_SETTLE_DURATION = 6000; // ms
    ...
}
```

The hack solution to change show/hide animation time is...

- Copy whole `BottomSheetBehavior` and `ViewDragHelper` classes souce code to your project (with different package name)
- In your file BottomSheetBehavior.java - change `import ViewDragHelper` to use your `ViewDragHelper` instead of original Android API class.
- In file ViewDragHelper.java - change duration returned by `computeAxisDuration` to satisfy your requirements, e.g. return exactly 400 ms.
- Use your `BottomSheetBehavior` class instead of original one.

It is very bad solution but it works in my project. Details below.

File ViewDragHelper.java

```
public class ViewDragHelper {
    // Additional fields and methods defined.
    private int mSettleDuration = BASE_SETTLE_DURATION;
    public void setDurationSpeedFactor(final float factor) {
        mSettleDuration = (int)(factor * BASE_SETTLE_DURATION);
    }
    private boolean mSkipAnimation = false;
    public void setSkipAnimation(final boolean skipAnimation) {
        this.mSkipAnimation = skipAnimation;
    }
    // Modified version of private function.
    private int computeAxisDuration(int delta, int velocity, int motionRange) {
        if (delta == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    
        final int width = mParentView.getWidth();
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;
        final float distanceRatio = Math.min(1f, (float) Math.abs(delta) / width);
        final float distance = halfWidth + halfWidth
            * distanceInfluenceForSnapDuration(distanceRatio);
        
        int duration;
        velocity = Math.abs(velocity);
        if (velocity > 0) {
            duration = 4 * Math.round(1000 * Math.abs(distance / velocity));
        } else {
            final float range = (float) Math.abs(delta) / motionRange;
            duration = (int) ((range + 1) * mSettleDuration);
        }
        return Math.min(duration, MAX_SETTLE_DURATION);
    }
    // Rest of original class body here...
}
```

File BottomSheetBehavior.java

```
// Comment out original ViewDragHelper and use above modified version.
//import androidx.customview.widget.ViewDragHelper;
import your.custom.ViewDragHelper;

public class BottomSheetBehavior<V extends View> extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V> {

    /**
     * Allows to set up ViewDragHelper immediately or when it is created.
     */
    public interface IDragHelperConfig {
        void onDragHelperCreated(ViewDragHelper viewDragHelper);
    }
    private IDragHelperConfig iDragHelperConfig;
    public void setIDragHelperConfig(IDragHelperConfig iDragHelperConfig) {
        this.iDragHelperConfig = iDragHelperConfig;
        if (viewDragHelper != null) {
            iDragHelperConfig.onDragHelperCreated(viewDragHelper);
        }
    }
    //...
    public boolean onLayoutChild(...) {
        if (viewDragHelper == null) {
            viewDragHelper = ViewDragHelper.create(parent, dragCallback);
            if (iDragHelperConfig != null) {
                iDragHelperConfig.onDragHelperCreated(viewDragHelper);
            }
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Sample code inside any android View initialization

```
    val params: CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams = myLayout.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
    val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior<FrameLayout>(myLayout.context, null)
    // Optionally, set the height of the bottom sheet when it is collapsed (usefull for experiments).
    // behavior.peekHeight = 20
    
    // Configure bottom sheet behavior.
    behavior.setIDragHelperConfig {
        // Set how many times to slow the speed of the animation
        // (relative to original Android animation speed).
        it.setDurationSpeedFactor(20f)

        // Optionally, turn off animation
        // Useful when entering a new activity and 
        // initial animation is not desired.
        it.setSkipAnimation(false)
    }
    params.behavior = behavior
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add animations in bottom sheet.
h

```
      // init the bottom sheet behavior
        BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(mBottomSheet);

        // change the state of the bottom sheet
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

        // set callback for changes
        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                // Called every time when the bottom sheet changes its state.
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                if (isAdded()) {
                    animateBottomSheetArrows(slideOffset);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void animateBottomSheetArrows(float slideOffset) {
        // Animate counter-clockwise
        mLeftArrow.setRotation(slideOffset * -180);
        // Animate clockwise
        mRightArrow.setRotation(slideOffset * 180); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to add animations to the bottom sheet, I just want to know the duration of the default animation.

Comment: Update: Regarding your example using callbacks, I cannot do that. I am using a MVVM pattern so that my logic has no direct access to the view, only via observer. Using the given bottom sheet state as a Two-Way-Binding is possible but I would prefer a fix duration for different reasons.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He's asking for how to change the animation duration, not animate something relative to its slide offset...

Comment: @Mordag the default animation duration is 500 mils

Comment: @Mordag this means you use MVVM in wrong way.  You must be eligible to use all ui based logic in one location with MVVM or not. You can animate your animation by progress with this slide offset. It is better than giving duration. Because if user slides with his finger, your animation will progress with botttomSheet sliding offset.